# "Invalid column name x" and "There is already an object named 'x' in the database"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I'm using Swagger API v1 OAS3 to execute a stored procedure in SSMS v15.0.18386 using T-SQL. However, the weird part is that even though I get an error message in my server response, executing it directly via my Swagger UI still works and gives me the intended result. I assume it has something to do with the way I create and drop temporary tables in combination with creating a new column for each temporary table before dropping it. I'd like to just ignore the error message, but I think it's causing my frontend to refuse making it work.

The error message I get from my server via Swagger:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
> Invalid column name 'Category'.
> Invalid column name 'Category'.
> Invalid column name 'Category'.
> Invalid column name 'Category'.
> There is already an object named 'rscopy' in the database.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, IEnumerable`1 parameters)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.ExecuteSqlRaw(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, String sql, Object[] parameters)   at API.Controllers.CruiseLineController.CopyShip(Int32 shipId, String newShipName, String newShipCode) in CLController.cs:line 87   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Error Number:207,State:1,Class:16

My T-SQL code:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyShip]
    (@ShipId int,
     @ShipName nvarchar(150),
     @ShipCode nvarchar(8))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @CruiselineId int, @NewShipId int;

    SET @CruiselineId = (SELECT [CruiselineId] FROM [dbo].Ships 
                         WHERE ShipId = @ShipId);

    ---- CREATING COPY OF Ships
    SELECT * 
    INTO shicopy
    FROM [dbo].Ships 
    WHERE ShipId = @ShipId

    UPDATE shicopy SET [Name] = @ShipName
    UPDATE shicopy SET [ShipCode] = @ShipCode

    INSERT INTO Ships 
        SELECT
            [CruiselineId], [Name], [ShipCode], [ClassId],
            [guestNumber], [staffNumber], [creationYear],
            [weight], [length], [passagerDeck], [handicapCabins],
            [nationality]
        FROM shicopy

    DROP TABLE shicopy;

    -- Declaring a new int variable and setting its value to be 
    -- the highest number in the ShipId column of the Ships 
    -- table (a.k.a. the new ShipId of the newly created Ship).
    
    --DECLARE @NewShipId int;
    SET @NewShipId = (SELECT MAX(ShipId) FROM [dbo].[Ships]);

    -- CREATING COPY OF Cabins
    SELECT * 
    INTO cccopy
    FROM [dbo].CabinCategory 
    WHERE ShipId = @ShipId

    UPDATE cccopy SET ShipId = @NewShipId

    INSERT INTO CabinCategory 
        SELECT
            [ShipId], [CabinType], [BalconySize], [MinSize], [MaxSize],
            [NoOfBeds], [Category], [HexCodes], [Description],
            [LongDescription], [LongDescriptonSE], [LongDescriptionNO],
            [HeaderDescriptionSE], [HeaderDescriptionNO],
            [FreeTextField], [FreeTextFieldSE], [FreeTextFieldNO],
            [CabinCategoryIdOld]
        FROM cccopy

    DROP TABLE cccopy;

    -- CREATING COPY OF BENEFITS
    SELECT * 
    INTO cbcopy
    FROM [dbo].[CabinToBenefits] 
    WHERE ShipId = @ShipId

    UPDATE cbcopy SET ShipId = @NewShipId

    ALTER TABLE cbcopy
        ADD Category nvarchar(255);

    EXEC (
    'Update B 
    set
    B.[Category] = bse.[Category]
    from dbo.[cbcopy] B 
    Inner join 
    dbo.CabinCategory bse on B.CabinCategoryId = BSE.CabinCategoryId

    Update B 
    set
    B.CabinCategoryId = bse.CabinCategoryId 
    from dbo.cbcopy B 
    Inner join 
    dbo.CabinCategory bse on B.Category = BSE.Category and B.ShipId = BSE.ShipId'
    )

    INSERT INTO CabinToBenefits
    SELECT [BenefitsId]
      ,[CabinCategoryId]
      ,[ShipId] FROM cbcopy

    DROP TABLE cbcopy;

...
...

---- CREATING COPY OF RestaurantToSeating

    Select * into rscopy
    FROM [dbo].[RestaurantToSeating] where ShipId = @ShipId

    update rscopy set ShipId = @NewShipId

    ALTER TABLE rscopy
    ADD Category nvarchar(255);

    EXEC (
    'Update B 
    set
    B.[Category] = bse.[Category]
    from dbo.rscopy B 
    Inner join 
    dbo.Restaurant bse on B.RestaurantId = BSE.RestaurantId

    Update B 
    set
    B.RestaurantId = bse.RestaurantId
    from dbo.rscopy B 
    Inner join 
    dbo.Restaurant bse on B.Category = BSE.Category and B.ShipId = BSE.ShipId'
    )


    INSERT INTO RestaurantToSeating
    SELECT [RestaurantId]
      ,[SeatingId]
      ,[ShipID] FROM rscopy

    DROP TABLE rscopy;
END
```

As you can see, I'm using the same code for creating other temporary tables besides the one mentioned in the error message (`'rscopy'`) and yet it's the only one that's underlined as an error. Perhaps because it is the last temp table (with many-to-many variables) I create in my stored procedure?

Either way, given what I have, I can't quite see why my code is causing me this error - especially not when it actually works when I execute it via my API UI.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you're doing here is a little bizarre to say the least - however you are not using *temporary tables* - you are creating permanent tables so if you execute this concurrently you are going to run into the error described.

Comment: @Stu so what would the solution be? Prefix all temporary tables with '#'?

Comment: The `rscopy` and `Category` is really not necessary. You can insert directly into `RestaurantToSeating` by selecting from `RestaurantToSeating`

Comment: @Squirrel As shown in the code, I have to make changes to the data of each table before I insert it back into itself. However I'd love to see exactly what you had in mind if your solution does what I had intended.

Comment: Also don't roll your own `IDENTITY` column, that feature exists for a reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't copy into a temporary table only to delete it afterwards. Just insert directly from the original.

Also:

- Don't roll your own `IDENTITY` column with `SELECT MAX`. Use a proper `IDENTITY` column and get the previous value using `OUTPUT` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.
- Don't quote every column name with `[]` when it doesn't need it. I haven't bothered removing them because I haven't got all day.
- I must say, I'm unclear why you have those joins, they don't appear necessary, but I've left them in.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CopyShip]
     @ShipId int,
     @ShipName nvarchar(150),
     @ShipCode nvarchar(8)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO Ships (
  [CruiselineId], [Name], [ShipCode], [ClassId],
  [guestNumber], [staffNumber], [creationYear],
  [weight], [length], [passagerDeck], [handicapCabins], [nationality]
)
SELECT
  [CruiselineId], @ShipName, @ShipCode, [ClassId],
  [guestNumber], [staffNumber], [creationYear],
  [weight], [length], [passagerDeck], [handicapCabins], [nationality]
FROM [dbo].Ships 
WHERE ShipId = @ShipId;

DECLARE @NewShipId int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- CREATING COPY OF Cabins
INSERT INTO CabinCategory (
  [ShipId], [CabinType], [BalconySize], [MinSize], [MaxSize],
  [NoOfBeds], [Category], [HexCodes], [Description],
  [LongDescription], [LongDescriptonSE], [LongDescriptionNO],
  [HeaderDescriptionSE], [HeaderDescriptionNO],
  [FreeTextField], [FreeTextFieldSE], [FreeTextFieldNO], [CabinCategoryIdOld]
)
SELECT
  @NewShipId, [CabinType], [BalconySize], [MinSize], [MaxSize],
  [NoOfBeds], [Category], [HexCodes], [Description],
  [LongDescription], [LongDescriptonSE], [LongDescriptionNO],
  [HeaderDescriptionSE], [HeaderDescriptionNO],
  [FreeTextField], [FreeTextFieldSE], [FreeTextFieldNO],
  [CabinCategoryIdOld]
FROM [dbo].CabinCategory cc
WHERE ShipId = @ShipId;


INSERT INTO CabinToBenefits (
  [BenefitsId]
 ,[CabinCategoryId]
 ,[ShipId]
)
SELECT B.[BenefitsId]
      ,bse2.CabinCategoryId
      ,@NewShipId
FROM [dbo].[CabinToBenefits] B
JOIN dbo.CabinCategory bse on B.CabinCategoryId = bse.CabinCategoryId
JOIN dbo.CabinCategory bse2 on bse2.[Category] = bse.Category and B.ShipId = bse2.ShipId
WHERE ShipId = @ShipId;

---- CREATING COPY OF RestaurantToSeating
INSERT INTO RestaurantToSeating (
  ShipId,
  RestaurantId,
  SeatingId
)
SELECT @NewShipId,
       bse.RestaurantId,
       rs.SeatingId 
FROM RestaurantToSeating rs
JOIN dbo.Restaurant r on rs.RestaurantId = r.RestaurantId 
JOIN dbo.Restaurant bse on r.Category = bse.Category and rs.ShipId = bse.ShipId
where rs.ShipId = @ShipId;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I will try it out at a later date. FYI the `[]` aren't manually/intentionally put in. It's an extension for SSMS that automatically inserts them when using the suggested options during coding. A pretty subjective thing to utilize, but I agree that it should objectively be used either universally or not at all.

Comment: **Update:** That worked, thanks! I guess SSMS was just angry at my overly complicated way of doing it. Cheers either way.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in comment, the `rscopy` and adding a column are not necessary. Your "creating copy" chuck of codes, may be replaced with following

```
---- CREATING COPY OF RestaurantToSeating

insert into RestaurantToSeating (ShipId, RestaurantId, SeatingId )
select ShipId       = @NewShipId,
       RestaurantId = bse.RestaurantId,
       SeatingId    = rs.SeatingId 
from   RestaurantToSeating rs
       inner join dbo.Restaurant r   on rs.RestaurantId = r.RestaurantId 
       inner join dbo.Restaurant bse on r.Category      = bse.Category 
                                    and rs.ShipId       = bse.ShipId
where  rs.ShipId = @ShipId
```